# Internet Explorer and IIS

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, iis-7

I have a site on my IIS and everything works fine in FireFox but in IE i just get to startpage and when i try to login in nothing happens.

I put in my userinformation and push a button then it suppose to get me to another page if the password etc was correct but nothing happens in IE but works in FireFox. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, my car won't start, do you know what's wrong?  I'm kidding of course, but from an outsider reading the question, that's how much information you're giving.  Try and give as much detail as you can, for example does the page do a lot of JavaScript, are you getting an error in IE in status bar on the left, any other symptoms?

Comment: Do you have any javascript in the page? Can you also tell the version of IE you are using? What happens exactly when the user clicks on the submit/login button.

Comment: It seems like it was a dns name problem.

I have no javascript on that page all it does is checking if your username and password is "correct" and redirect if it is. All that happend when i pushed the button was a postback but nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can trace the difference by using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)?